# How to fix MySQL installation in Ubuntu:20.04 Docker container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, docker

invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.
...
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/0: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/1: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/2: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/3: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/4: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/5: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/6: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/7: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/8: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/9: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/10: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/11: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/12: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/13: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/14: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/15: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/16: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/17: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/18: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/19: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/20: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/21: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/22: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/23: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/24: Permission denied
Cannot stat file /proc/3352/fd/25: Permission denied

Comment: Please fix your question, my suggest is give proper formatting add context so people will understand well. Go phase by phase mention what you trying to do, what happened after that logs and clear statement about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found solution by remove current ubuntu:20.04 docker container, to install ubuntu lastest version for compatibility with docker.
And i install mysql-server

```
apt install mysql-server
```